# Redux middleware with createApi RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-middleware

I was using `redux-toolkit` for authentication and now I want to do a middleware check before I go to my login page or any page to verify user is user logged in. How can I do it with redux `createMiddlewareListener()` from `redux-toolkit`.
Heres my code implementing createApi.

```js
export const loginApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "loginApi",
  tagTypes: ["Login"],
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: appConfig.apiUrl, jsonContentType: "application/json" }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    login: build.mutation({
      query: ({ username, password }) => ({
        url: "/auth/login",
        method: "POST",
        body: { username, password },
      }),
    }),
    getMe: build.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/auth/me",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${TokenUtil.getToken()}`,
        },
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useLoginMutation, useGetMeQuery } = loginApi;
```

and heres my `configureStore`

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [loginApi.reducerPath]: loginApi.reducer,
    //...other reducers
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware()concat(loginApi.middleware),
});
```

I've looked some redux middleware implementation and I can only find redux middleware implementation in `createSlice()`.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: i want to create a middleware to know wether the user has logged in or not

Comment: Read about Redux middleware [here](https://redux.js.org/understanding/history-and-design/middleware). Middleware isn't a Redux-Toolkit "thing", it's just Redux. That said, you may be asking a bit of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) question. What is it you are actually trying to accomplish here? Protect access to some pages your app is rendering? Does the `login` endpoint return any data? Do you save any "auth" state that you could just check there if a user is authenticated? In other words, creating a middleware probably isn't the correct tool for what you want to do.

Comment: yea you're right, also sorry about the confusion. I found a solution, now i just simply save user token in my redux state and make every request with the token, that way i know wether the user has logged in or not. Thank you for helping